# How to use the module List in Oz

Tags: list, module, oz, mozart

I found info about a module in Oz that contains procedures operating on lists here: https://mozart.github.io/mozart-v1/doc-1.4.0/base/list.html

But I have been trying different procedures in different ways, for example:

```
declare
proc {Length L}
   I
in
   {List.length +L ?I}
   {Browse I}
end

declare
L=[1 2 3 4]
in
{Length L}
```

And what I get is a type error, I hope you can help me to know why, I'm very new using OZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the arguments you pass to `List.length`. You should not use the '+' symbol. It is the operator for the addition. Simply call

```
{List.length L ?I}
```

The '+' symbol is used in the documentation to show what is the purpose of the arguments. The '+' symbol denotes an input argument while '?' denotes an output argument.

Besides, you can use '?' in your code for clarity, it is supported by Oz.

Also, the `List` module should be imported by default. So you do not have to define a function `Length` that uses `List.length`, you can simply use

```
{Browse {Length [1 2 3 4 5]}}
```

to browse the length of the list given as argument.